# WPF: How do I apply custom formatting to a ListView?

Tags: wpf, listview, binding, formatting, styles

My ListView is petty simple:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ActiveCounters}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn  Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            <GridViewColumn  Header="Value"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" />
            <GridViewColumn  Header="As Of Date"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=AsOfDate}" />
            <GridViewColumn  Header="Duration"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Duration}" />
            <GridViewColumn  Header="Last Modified Date"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Timestamp}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

What I want to do is:

- Format "Value" using the built-in format "D0"
- Format "AsOfDate" and "Last Modified Date" using the custom string "MMM d hh:mm:ss tt"
- Format "Duration" with a function defined as "String DurationString(TimeSpan)

Comment: check out http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2008/05/19/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-stringformat.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Value and AsOfDate columns use `StringFormat` attribute - a new feature of WPF 3.5 SP1.
More about it here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2008/05/19/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-stringformat.aspx

http://elegantcode.com/2009/04/07/wpf-stringformat-in-xaml-with-the-stringformat-attribute/

If you want to call a custom function on a bound value, then implement a value converter for that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx

You can call your custom function from convert method.

Answer (score 5):

`StringFormat` can be added to your binding statement. For example

```
<GridViewColumn
   Header="As Of Date"
   DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=AsOfDate, StringFormat={}{0:MMM d hh:mm:ss tt}}" />
```

See [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2008/05/19/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-stringformat.aspx) for more usage examples

Comment: Well that handles two out of the three cases. But what about calling a custom function?